# .load() not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple program that is refreshing an page every 100 milliseconds. But when i am trying to run it i am simply getting an blank page.Here is my html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('demo.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>

</script>
```

Please help me to solve this problem as i am beginner to jquery.Thanks in advance

Comment: your html is nonsense....you have no head and the body is in the script tag...

Comment: was `$('#load_tweets').load('demo.php').fadeIn("slow");` workibng without timeout?

Comment: It works for the first time?

Comment: You wrote BODY inside SCRIPT TAG ? :) OMG GREAT !!!!

Comment: It not works for the first time too

Comment: thanks partik joshi i know html but i have copied it from 9lessons.info

Comment: You copy paste things without even understanding what's happening, you need to understand what you're copy pasting. In this case you're copy pasting something that's simply **wrong**. Create a basic html side that's html5 valid, then create the javascript and check if everything is still valid, then you can check your developer tools for errors to see what's going wrong. Your current problem is that you have simply invalid html and invalid javascript. You can't just write html inside of javascript, fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is closing script tag 
try like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="load_tweets"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeOut() instead.

```
setTimeout("yourfunction()", 1000);   // call yourfunction() after 1 second

function yourfunction(){

//do what you want
}
```

Also correct your HTML!